# design audio amplifier circuit

Tags: transistors, capacitor, resistors, diodes

I wish to design audio amplifier circuit. Hear I use two stage of amplifiers. 1st stage amplifies 100mv to 1.2V peak @ 2KHz.

[image]

Q1. When I change the frequency to 50Hz output becomes to 210mv peak signal. At that time when I changed c3 cap to 100uf again it amplify 1.25V peak signal.  I need to amplify audio signal therefore amplitude is changing according to frequency. What can I do for it?

Q2. 2nd stage is power amplify part. Output of at that stage 180mv peak shows @ 2 KHz signal. That mean 2nd stage amplitude is decreased how it happened and solution for it.
[image]

Comment: Did you calculate the input impedance? Is the coupling capacitor large enough for that impedance?

Comment: I have the tomato sitting on the rock almost working.  How do I finish building the jetliner?

Comment: You simply use a dual-emitter capacitor that you wire up to your [turbo encabulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ac7G7xOG2Ag); the sinusoidal deplanaration induced by the jetliner's triple-retro-suscestibility can be used as an additional source of capacitive reactance, @OlinLathrop!

Comment: Although your comments are pretty funny, this question is much better than the linked one. This can probably be answered.